# How to trigger script with button press on controller

Tags: raspbian

I have a Logitech wireless controller connected to my raspberry pi. I am trying to figure out how I can trigger a simple script by pressing a button on the controller.

I have no idea what to search for, and I am not even sure the pi is responding to the controller outside of the steam link app. Any direction in how I can go about doing this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: My guess is the controller emulates a keyboard unless it’s the Harmony range then it could be Bluetooth, controller or IR.  Can you please edit your question to include details on the controller (pref with a link to the manuals)?

Comment: your question is not about RPi .... it is a linux question .... do your research at linux websites .... you'll probably have better luck finding info

Comment: Maybe trying to search on Logitech website or on github any API for communicate with your wireless controller. Have you try XInput ? [Here](https://pypi.org/project/XInput-Python/) is the python project. If XInput work then you can trigger an event in `def process_button_event(self, event)` for example.